# Getting and printing data in one loop

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def print_dsv_data():
    for d in self.data:
        print('#'.join(map(str, self.get_data(d))))
```

I would like to create a method `get_dsv_data()` which gets the data in DSV format, meaning it would look like:

```
def get_dsv_data():
    r = []
    for d in self.data:
        r.append('#'.join(map(str, self.get_data(d))))
    return r

def print_dsv_data():
    for d in self.get_dsv_data:
        print(d)
```

The problem with that soultion is that I loop through data twice and I'm trying to figure out how I can do it with one loop, something like:

```
def get_dsv_data():
    r = []
    for d in self.data:
        r.append('#'.join(map(str, self.get_data(d))))
    return r

def print_dsv_data():
    print(self.get_dsv_data())
```

But that way I just print the list as is.
Is it possible to achive? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: the second loop that you are concerned about is the print ?

Comment: @SaifAsif yes. The first loop creates a list of data and the second loop prints the data of the list. Now, the first loop does not have to create a list. It could be a dict or other structures.

Comment: If you just don't want to write the loop and print part, you can use `pprint` module although am sure it loops internally

Comment: is get_dsv_data as class member function?

Comment: @abhilb both are

Comment: then implement the `__repr__` and the `__str__` functions. when you get the data set a string representation of the class too. So when you want to print you don't have to use a for loop again

Comment: @abhilb Is not it possible to just create a dict or string and return it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set an optional argument in the get_dsv_data, which toggles a print function?

```
def get_dsv_data(print_flag=False, delimiter='#'):
    r = []
    for d in self.data:
        row_str = delimiter.join(map(str, self.get_data(d)))
        if print_flag:
            print(row_str)
        r.append(row_str)
    return r
```

This way, you only loop once.